# Как правильно работать с std::shared_ptr внутри класса?

Tags: c++, указатели

Класс, одно из его полей это `std::shared_ptr<type> p = nullptr;`, указатель будет установлен позже. Достаточно ли будет в деструкторе вызвать `p.reset()` или нужно предварительно проверять `if (p)`?

Есть метод `setPtr(const std::shared_ptr<type> newP) { if (p.unique()) p.reset(); p = newP;}`, была ли лишней проверка на уникальность или при присвоении нового значения по старому значению reset происходит самостоятельно (счётчик уменьшается)?

В описанном мной случае есть что-то, что может привести к утечке памяти? компилятор самый свежий.

Comment: если посмотреть в стандарт, то можно увидеть, что с 17 плюсов unique уже задеприкейчен, а с 20 - удален. И это хорошая задача -объяснить, почему так сделали.

Comment: Вообще ничего не делайте с ним в деструкторе. Он сам за собой убирает. Утечек не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, вызов деструктора у `shared_ptr` как раз и приводит к отмотке счетчика ссылок и удалению подшефного объека, если счетчик смотался до нуля - собственно, в этом и смысл умных указателей - чтобы они сами следили за своими подопечными без написания с вашей стороны всякой ерунды в деструкторах.

Таким образом, вы используете умный указатель, но в виду тотального непонимания, как он работает, делаете его работу буквально за него:

```
setPtr(const std::shared_ptr<type> newP) { if (p.unique()) p.reset(); p = newP;}
```

Так как указатель умный, здесь достаточно сделать присваивание. Все умные действия указатель сделает сам.

[RTFM!](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/how-to-create-and-use-shared-ptr-instances?view=msvc-170)

Comment: если во время работы программы указатель снова будет выставлен в nullptr, затем будет вызван деструктор класса, то никакая ошибка не выйдет? reset() сам проверит, что указатель не нулевой?

Comment: Да, поэтому указатель такой умный. Замечание в сторону: delete nullptr разрешено стандартом и просто ничего не делает.